# Modify on the fly value of long running process for Mocking purposes in Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I have the following method:

```
public async Task ScrapeObjects(int page)
{
    try
    {
        while (!isObjectSearchCompleted)
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(_apiSettings.Value.FundaUrl)
            {
                Query = $"test"
            };
            var result = await _apiCaller.GetResponseAsync<ResponseModel>(builder.Uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            if (result != null)
            {
                foreach (var obj in result.Objects)
                {
                    UpdateDictionary(propertiesAmount, obj.name);
                }
            }
            if (!fundaResult.Objects.Any())
            {
                isObjectSearchCompleted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                page++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "Request limit exceeded.")
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            ScrapeObjects(page);
        }
        Log.Fatal(ex, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I am trying to unit test it. However this is a long time running process. I have control over **_apiCaller** since I am mocking it.
What I am trying to do is testing the following 2 scenarios:

1) the **_apiCaller** returns the correct result the first time. My dictionary is updated through **UpdateDictionary**. The second call instead returns no result and therefore the whole method reaches its end. The goal of my test is to ensure that my dictionary has been updated.

or

2) the **_apiCaller** returns the correct result the first time. My dictionary is updated through **UpdateDictionary**. The second call instead throws an exception and my method terminates. The goal of my test is to ensure that my dictionary has been updated.

In both cases I need to change the behavior of my method (of my mocked **_apiCaller**) on the fly or at least after the first time it's called. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, Do not mix async-await with `Thread.Sleep` Use `Task.Delay`

Comment: Also from a design perspective, If request limit exceeded, the response tends to tel you how long to wait before you can make further requests. If your response does that then I suggest using that to determine how long to delay for the next request.

Comment: The delay period could also be a configurable API setting that can be changed when unit testing.

Comment: There are too many unknown variables missing from the currently shown code that make it difficult to properly assess the actual issue and to provide proper suggestions.

Comment: @Nkosi wait wait.. the **Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));** is already there on purpose to make sure that the amount of requests doesn't exceed the max number of allowed request. The api I am contacting allows 60 requests per minute and that's why I wait 1 sec between each call. But still.. I would like to be on the safe side and for that reason I inserted a try/catch in case I exceed anyway the maximum request

Comment: @Nkosi I would like now to be able to test that scenario.. or in general I would like to be able to get out of the loop somehow. That **scrapeObjects** method continues scraping until my external api call through **_apiCaller** returns no value anymore. How can I make sure that in my unit test I mock my **_apiCaller** to return the right value **and only then** change its mocking behavior to return an empty response (or exception) ? In this way I am able to test the "correct" behavior of the service

Comment: Use [`SetupSequence`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#miscellaneous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SetupSequence`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#miscellaneous) to adjust the behavior of the mock when invoked.

> 1) the _apiCaller returns the correct result the first time. My dictionary is updated through UpdateDictionary. The second call instead returns no result and therefore the whole method reaches its end. The goal of my test is to ensure that my dictionary has been updated.

```
apiMock.SetupSequence(_ => _.GetResponseAsync<ResponseModel>(It.IsAny<Uri>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(correctResponseModel)) // returns the correct result the first time.
    .Returns(Task.FromResult((ResponseModel)null)); // The second call instead returns no result
```

> 2) the _apiCaller returns the correct result the first time. My dictionary is updated through UpdateDictionary. The second call instead throws an exception and my method terminates. The goal of my test is to ensure that my dictionary has been updated.

```
apiMock.SetupSequence(_ => _.GetResponseAsync<ResponseModel>(It.IsAny<Uri>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(correctResponseModel)) // returns the correct result the first time.
    .Throws(new HttpRequestException("Request limit exceeded.")); //second call throws an exception
```

That said, do not mix `async-await` with `Thread.Sleep` Use `Task.Delay`

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

//...
```

You are opening yourself unwanted behavior in the `catch` since the retry call is not being awaited.

```
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    if (ex.Message == "Request limit exceeded.")
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        ScrapeObjects(page); //<-- not awaited.
    }
    Log.Fatal(ex, ex.Message);
}
```

I would suggest researching Retry Pattern to better handle that scenario in your design

Comment: It works greatly :) thanks a lot and also for the "await Task.Delay" instead of Thread.Sleep!